# ERROR 10818 - Can't infer register because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I'm working on a code of a modified Gauss-Jordan eliminator and I'm getting the errors:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

PACKAGE matriz IS
    TYPE matrix IS ARRAY (NATURAL RANGE <>) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO 7);
    TYPE vector IS ARRAY (NATURAL RANGE <>) OF INTEGER;
END matriz;

USE work.matriz.all;
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

ENTITY bloco2 IS
    GENERIC (m: integer:= 4;
                n: integer:= 7;
                k: integer:= 3);
    PORT (clk,rst: IN STD_LOGIC;
            s: IN vector(1 TO n);
            G: IN matrix(1 TO m);
            Gr0, Gr: OUT matrix(1 TO m));
END bloco2;

ARCHITECTURE bloco2 OF bloco2 IS

SIGNAL Grt: matrix(1 TO m):= (OTHERS=>(OTHERS=>'0'));
SIGNAL Gr0t: matrix(1 TO m):= (OTHERS =>(OTHERS=>'0'));
SIGNAL st: vector(1 TO n):= (OTHERS=>0);

SIGNAL temp1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO n):= (OTHERS=>'0');
SIGNAL temp2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO n):= (OTHERS=>'0');
SIGNAL verify: STD_LOGIC:= '0';

BEGIN

    PROCESS(clk, rst, G, Grt, Gr0t, st, s, verify, temp1, temp2)
    VARIABLE L: INTEGER:= 1;
    VARIABLE c: INTEGER:= 1;
    VARIABLE count: INTEGER:= 0;
    BEGIN

        Grt<=G;
        st<=s;

        IF rst='0' THEN
            IF (rising_edge(clk))THEN
                IF count <= 3 THEN
                    IF Grt(L)(st(c))='1' THEN
                                Gr0t(L)(st(c))<='1';
                                FOR i IN 1 TO m LOOP
                                    verify <= Grt(i)(st(c));
                                    FOR j IN 1 TO n LOOP
                                        IF ((i/=L) and (verify/='0')) THEN
                                            Grt(i)(j)<= Grt(L)(j) xor Grt(i)(j);
                                        END IF;
                                    END LOOP;
                                END LOOP;
                                count:=count+1;
                                L:=L+1;
                                c:=c+1;
                    END IF;

                    IF Grt(L)(st(c))='0' THEN
                        FOR i IN 1 TO m LOOP
                                IF i > L THEN
                                    IF Grt(i)(st(c)) ='1' THEN
                                     temp1<= Grt(L)(1 TO n);
                                     temp2<= Grt(i)(1 TO n);
                                     Grt(i)(1 TO n)<= temp1;
                                     Grt(L)(1 TO n)<= temp2;
                                     exit;
                                    END IF;
                                END IF;
                        END LOOP;   

                        IF Grt(L)(st(c)) /='1' THEN
                            c:=c+1;
                        END IF;
                    END IF;

                END IF;
            END IF;

        END IF;

        IF rst='1' THEN
            Gr0t <= (OTHERS=>(OTHERS=>'0'));
            Grt <= (OTHERS => (OTHERS =>'0'));

        END IF;
    Gr<=Grt;
    Gr0<=Gr0t;
END PROCESS;
END bloco2;
```

> Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Grt[4][7]" at bloco2.vhd(50) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge.

**P.S.:** It happens for every position of matrix Grt.

Could someone help me to understand what's happening here?
**P.S.:** In my code, I'm just using `IF` structures, without any kind of `ELSE` or `ELSIF`, because I've read this could be the cause of the problem, but in my case this tip didn't work.

Comment: Probably the separate asynchronous reset at the end is confusing synth, it is after all an assignment outside the clocked process. Use one of the normal forms combining reset and rising_edge(clock) in the same if/then/elsit statement. ( That "tip" is garbage by the way)

Comment: Please read you vendor's HDL developer guide about proper VHDL code pattern on how to describe synchronous and asynchronous circuits.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of basic things to know.

- Signals only update when a process suspends.  This will be at either a process sensitivity list (your case) or at a wait statement (typically in a testbench).
- Synthesis tools only understand a very limited subset of the language and are particularly picky WRT flip-flops.
- If your process is properly structured for portability with synthesis tools, then you only need clock and asynchronous controls (and asynchronously loaded data but don't) on the sensitivity list.

Lets re-write your code in a 1076.6-1999 fashion.

Since your process does not have a wait statement, all the code executes during the same delta cycle.  Any signal assignment done outside of the clock/reset portion of the process can be done concurrently instead.   Hence, we will code the following in the architecture code region of the design (and not in a process):

```
Grt<=G;
st<=s;
Gr<=Grt;
Gr0<=Gr0t;
```

The reset you coded is asynchronous.   One portable template is:

```
PROCESS(clk, rst)
BEGIN
    IF rst='1' THEN
      . . . 

    elsif (rising_edge(clk))THEN
      .  .  .

    END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

Your code is closer to the template below.   One that I like, but it is slightly less portable.  Note in this branch, the clock branch is not conditional on reset and any assignments in the reset branch simply override settings in the clock branch.  I recommend starting with the above one first and get it working correctly in simulation and synthesis, and then switch back if you really want to.

```
PROCESS(clk, rst)
BEGIN
    if (rising_edge(clk))THEN
      .  .  .

    END IF;
    IF rst='1' THEN
      . . . 
    END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

Below is your code with the concurrent signals factored out.   I did not make any changes for other potentially problematic issues.

```
PROCESS(clk, rst)
VARIABLE L: INTEGER:= 1;
VARIABLE c: INTEGER:= 1;
VARIABLE count: INTEGER:= 0;
BEGIN
    IF rst='1' THEN
        Gr0t <= (OTHERS=>(OTHERS=>'0'));
        Grt <= (OTHERS => (OTHERS =>'0'));

    elsif (rising_edge(clk))THEN
            IF count <= 3 THEN
                IF Grt(L)(st(c))='1' THEN
                            Gr0t(L)(st(c))<='1';
                            FOR i IN 1 TO m LOOP
                                verify <= Grt(i)(st(c));
                                FOR j IN 1 TO n LOOP
                                    IF ((i/=L) and (verify/='0')) THEN
                                        Grt(i)(j)<= Grt(L)(j) xor Grt(i)(j);
                                    END IF;
                                END LOOP;
                            END LOOP;
                            count:=count+1;
                            L:=L+1;
                            c:=c+1;
                END IF;

                IF Grt(L)(st(c))='0' THEN
                    FOR i IN 1 TO m LOOP
                            IF i > L THEN
                                IF Grt(i)(st(c)) ='1' THEN
                                 temp1<= Grt(L)(1 TO n);
                                 temp2<= Grt(i)(1 TO n);
                                 Grt(i)(1 TO n)<= temp1;
                                 Grt(L)(1 TO n)<= temp2;
                                 exit;
                                END IF;
                            END IF;
                    END LOOP;   

                    IF Grt(L)(st(c)) /='1' THEN
                        c:=c+1;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

Some things to think about:

- Grt0 only gets assigned in one place.   It will be accumulating 1's after reset.
- What is your intent of Temp1 and Temp2?  Signals do not update instantaneously, so they do not swap values.   If you want this behavior, either use a variable or remove Temp1 and Temp2 and do the assignment directly.
- What is your intent of Verify?  Based on its usage, it probably needs to be a variable too.